# Remove attachments from PDF files from command line on Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, command-line-interface

anyone know of a utility or script that can remove files attached within a PDF file? I am using pdftk to get the attached files using the unpack_files option, however there is not a way to remove those files from the PDF on this software, which is what I really need to happen. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found a utility called Coherent PDF which will do this in case someone else is needing this.